# Arranging elements using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

### [image]

I have been trying to position a button to right right of another button. above is an example showing you what I mean.

I built it using Bootstrap. They have a navbar feature which will do the layout for me. Great feature, but I do not know why it keeps making a new row. I have tried `right: 0` and positioning but none of that would work. It will stay in that same spot every time. I currently do not know what is causing this error. Thank you for your time!

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar" style="position: relative; width: 93%;left: 3%;">

    <div class="navbar-inner">

    <div class="brand" style="padding-left: 0%;">
          <a href="www.investorsfortunes.com">
    <!--  <img class="img-polaroid" src="Images/logo.jpg"> -->
    Investorsfortunes.com 
      </a>
      </div>

  <ul class="nav" style="text-align: center">
  <li class="divider-vertical"><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
  <li class="divider-vertical"><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
  <li class="divider-vertical"><a href="#">Attornies</a></li>
  <li class="divider-vertical"><a href="#">Appraisers</a></li>

  </ul>


  <form class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
   <button type="submit" class="btn floatRight">Sign in</button>
</form>

<!-- SIGN-UP AREA -->    
            <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary floatRight" data- 
       toggle="modal">Sign-Up</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  
         labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-  
            hidden="true">x</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Sign-Up</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="well span8">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Your First Name">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Your Last Name">
        <label>Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Your email address">
        <label>Password</label>
         <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
          <label>Retype Password</label>
         <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why do you have `width: 93%; left: 3%` in the `.navbar`? thats going to mess up the structure bootstrap sets up

Comment: @ashley I used it because if I do not include it, it will make the top part of the page white but I actually want it to be the same size of my body. Is there a way around this?

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Drm5t/1/ . you will need to stretch the screen to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form is a block element is HTML.
either set the Sign Up inside the form or set the style of the form to be inline-block

```
<form class="form-inline" style="display:inline-block;">
```

Comment: Well - in raw HTML it is working - maybe something override it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using twitter bootstrap, so maybe you can use

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Left</button>
    <button class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code inside the form. Like that...

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
   <button type="submit" class="btn floatRight">Sign in</button>

<!-- SIGN-UP AREA -->    
            <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary floatRight" data- 
       toggle="modal">Sign-Up</a>
</form>
```